# cocos2d-javascript iphone mozilla/DebugOnly.h not found

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i install cocos2d-javascript and  run into iphone , i got this error

> mozilla/DebugOnly.h not found on the HashTable.h file

my HashTable.h code is

```
include "mozilla/Attributes.h
include "mozilla/DebugOnly.h
```

have any idea for my problem ?? 
i have already update cocos2d and try to install again, but still not work . 
here is error message

[image: mozilla/DebugOnly.h not found on HashTable.h file]

Comment: fixed. thanks.
The problem was that the templates were not updated for SpiderMonkey v20. commit that fixes it:
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/commit/5eb1eb70c3b35ca5b1ef1479f041992691d04863

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error. Doesn't seem to be in the issue list either...

#### UPDATE:

Reported on the issue queue: https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/issues/detail?id=1487

#### EDIT:

In the forum too: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/31640/page/8

## Manual Fix:

So, after doing some git pulling and submodule updating, I found the DebugOnly.h IS included in cocos2d, but isn;t included in the project.

#### Run this:

```
cp ~/Documents/Repos/cocos2d-iphone/external/JavaScript/SpiderMonkey/ios/include/mozilla/DebugOnly.h [PROJECT]/libs/SpiderMonkey/ios/include/mozilla/
```